# Ruby, Shortest way to create Key, value pair out of hash?

Tags: ruby

I have hash like this:

```
h = {
   type1: [1,2,3,4],
   type2: [1,2,3,4],
   type3: [1,2,3,4]
}
```

I want output like this:

```
[[:type1,1],[:type1,2],[:type1,3],[:type1,4],[:type2,1],[:type2,2] ... ]
```

I will not be using it in actual code as it's much more easier to write, understand and read simple block statement, but for curiosity sake. What is the very rubyist way to do it, disregarding any performance concerns if need be.

Comment: Your example hash `h` does not compile, and for same reason your expected output is also not achievable - you cannot have variable name show up as values in array.  I am downvoting for that reason,  I will remove the downvote if you can provide example that are proper Ruby

Comment: Ditto on @Wand's comment. To clarify, where Wand says "...values in array." he's not referring to "values", in the "key-value" sense. He's referring to the keys; e.g., `type` is presumably a variable or method whose value is unknown. Perhaps you mean it to be a literal such as `:type1` or `"type1"`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO isn't a write code for me site, instead we help debug your code. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages and "[mcve]". Your question is very broad, and doesn't show any effort in coding or researching the problem.

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes i meant it literal sense, type1 is key's name. it could be Food, Vechile, Clothing

Comment: @MuhammadUmer You need to update your question to reflect your actual intentions.  Don't make it difficult on people that would want to answer to have to sift through comments to figure out what you actually meant.

Comment: I have updated the question, now keys are symbols.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more way to do this:

```
h.flat_map {|k, v| [k].product v}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
h.flat_map{|k, a| a.map{|v| [k, v]}}
```

Edit: I realized it is the same as @max pleaner's answer.

Edit2: No, it wasn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested map:

```
h.map do |key, array_value|
  array_value.map do |item|
    [key, item]
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
irb(main):009:0> h = { a: [1,2,3], b: [4,5,6] }
=> {:a=>[1, 2, 3], :b=>[4, 5, 6]}
irb(main):010:0> h.map do |key, array_value|
irb(main):011:1*   array_value.map do |item|
irb(main):012:2*     [key, item]
irb(main):013:2>   end
irb(main):014:1> end
=> [[[:a, 1], [:a, 2], [:a, 3]], [[:b, 4], [:b, 5], [:b, 6]]]
irb(main):015:0>
```

To do the same thing with `keys` and `values` method as best I know:

```
result = []
h.values.each_with_index do |array, idx|
  array.each do |item|
    result[h[h.keys[idx]]] = item
  end
end
```

Comment: can't i use h.keys with h.values somehow

Comment: Thats whats happening in this answer. is there any reason you wouldn't want to use this?

Comment: This produces an array of arrays of arrays. An array of arrays is desired. That's why the other answers use `flat_map` rather than `map`.